# finding all solutions of an equation using counting

Tags: discrete-mathematics

lets say I have

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 17 $$

What are all the solutions for $$ x_i \ge 0? \quad \text{ where }  i=1,2,3,4$$

How about if $$ x_i \ge 0 \text{ ?} $$ And if $$ x_i \gt 1 \quad\text{ where } i =1,2,3,4$$

I tried following the example of the book. For the last one I got $$ C(4+10-1, 4-1) $$

No clue if it's correct. And confused on how to tackle the first two. Thanks.

Comment: The conventional locution is $x_i \ge 0 \text{ for }i=1,2,3,4$.  The word "where" is used in identifying one's conventions, as when one says "...where $T$ is the surface temperature and $\omega$ is the frequency", etc.  Some mathematicians do get sloppy about this sometimes and write "THEOREM: blahblahblah, where $w$ is a positive number" when they really mean "for _some_ positive number $w$" or "for _every_ positive number $w$", but that shouldn't be done. I edited for proper use of \text{} and for subscripts and some formatting. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: For the third one, your $10$ is wrong; it should be $17-4\cdot 2$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the second case. Can you post the original problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well this is a classic stars and bars problem. If $x_i \ge 0$ then you have:

$$\binom{17 + 4 - 1}{4-1} = \binom{20}{3} = 1140 \text{ solutions}$$

For the second problem write $x_i = 2 + k_i$, then the equation is reduced to $k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + k_4 = 9$, which can be easily solved simularly to the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a program in Visual Basic to be run in Excel, that lists the numbers for your first case.

```
Sub Macro1403106()
'
' Macro1403106
'
CONT = 1

For I = 0 To 17
For J = 0 To 17
For K = 0 To 17
For L = 0 To 17

Sum = I + J + K + L

If Sum = 17 Then
Cells(CONT, 1) = I
Cells(CONT, 2) = J
Cells(CONT, 3) = K
Cells(CONT, 4) = L
CONT = CONT + 1
End If

Next L
Next K
Next J
Next I

End Sub
```

With 1140 solutions as indicated by Stefan4024.